# how to check whether user is using right to left style of writing in word using office.js

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am working on office-addin which basically adds citations in the word documents. Format for my citation is :- (**citation-text**).
When user has selected **Left to Right** style of writing, it adds citation in the proper format as mentioned above, but if user has selected **Right to Left** style of writing the format of my citation changes as :- **citation-text))** i.e after inserting the citation into the document it pushes both the parenthesis to end of the citation text.
Is there any way i can detect whether user is using **LTR or RTL** style of writing so that i can format my citation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's currently possible to detect the direction of writing (LTR or RTL) using the Office JavaScript API. If you'd like to add this feature request to [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/), other people can vote on it there to give the Office PM team a sense of overall priority/demand as they plan for future updates to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll definitely put request on User Voice.